# foreach statement within ACF repeater

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, repeater, advanced-custom-fields

I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly? I have a nested ACF repeater, which is working fine, but the section are all displaying as one lone block.  I want to be able to break the blocks into columns. So I though to do this I would need a "foreach" statement so I could assign an id or class to each section, allowing me to be able to style each section individually - float and add margins etc.

I can't quite get it to work!

```
<div class="col-xl-12 food-section">


<?php
$rows = get_field('section_container');
if($rows) {
foreach($rows as $row):
?>

<div class="col-xl-6 section-test"> <?php
    if( have_rows('section_container') ) :  
    while( have_rows('section_container') ): the_row(); ?>

<h1><?php the_sub_field('section_heading'); ?></h1>
        <div class="section-image"><?php
            $image = get_sub_field('section_image');
            if( !empty($image) ): ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
        </div>

        <?php endif;

            if( have_rows('sub_section_container') ): 
            while( have_rows('sub_section_container') ): the_row();
            ?>
                <h2><?php the_sub_field('sub_section_heading'); ?></h2>
                <?php
                    if( have_rows('food_item') ): 
                    while( have_rows('food_item') ): the_row();
                ?>

<div id="menu-table">
    <h3 id="leftside"><?php the_sub_field('item_name'); ?></h3>
    <h4 id="rightside"><?php the_sub_field('price'); ?></h4>
    <div id="menu-description"><p><?php the_sub_field('item_description'); ?></p></div>
    <div class="stroke"></div>
</div>

                <?php   endwhile; //food_item
                    endif;  //food_item

            endwhile; //section_h1_container
            endif;  //section_h1_container

    endwhile; //section_container
    endif;  //section_container

    wp_reset_postdata();

    endforeach; }
?></div>

    </div><!-- food-section -->
```

Comment: you might get more views if you add php tag

Comment: The "while( have_rows('section_container') ): the_row();" is doing the same job as your foreach, and the "if( have_rows('section_container') ) :" is doing the same job as the if statement above your foreach. Take a look here to read up on nested repeaters: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/working-with-nested-repeaters/

Answer (score 1):

I've cleaned up your code, and I'm hoping I'm understanding your request. You had an unnecessary if and foreach at the top of the snippet, and a wp_reset_postdata() that is not needed at the end of a repeater call in ACF.

You can read more on nested repeaters here:

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/working-with-nested-repeaters/

```
<?php if( have_rows('section_container') ) : ?>
 <div class="col-xl-12 food-section"> 
      <?php while( have_rows('section_container') ): the_row(); ?>
           <div class="col-xl-6 section-test">
                <h1><?php the_sub_field('section_heading'); ?></h1>
                <div class="section-image">
                     <?php $image = get_sub_field('section_image');
                     if( !empty($image) ): ?>
                          <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
                     <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
                <?php if( have_rows('sub_section_container') ): 
                     while( have_rows('sub_section_container') ): the_row(); ?>
                          <h2><?php the_sub_field('sub_section_heading'); ?></h2>
                          <?php if( have_rows('food_item') ): 
                               while( have_rows('food_item') ): the_row(); ?>
                                    <div id="menu-table">
                                        <h3 id="leftside"><?php the_sub_field('item_name'); ?></h3>
                                        <h4 id="rightside"><?php the_sub_field('price'); ?></h4>
                                        <div id="menu-description"><p><?php the_sub_field('item_description'); ?></p></div>
                                        <div class="stroke"></div>
                                    </div>
                               <?php   endwhile; //food_item
                          endif;  //food_item
                     endwhile; //section_h1_container
                endif;  //section_h1_container ?>
           </div>
      <?php endwhile; //section_container ?>
 </div>
<?php endif;  //section_container ?>
```

This snippet checks if any rows are set for "section_container" if so, it creates the "food-section" div. It then loops through each row of "section_container". For each row, it creates a "section-test" div, and begins to populate it with the subfield data for that row. It then checks for the "sub_section_container" repeater inside your current row, and loops through the rows inside that nested repeater, and outputs the data.